# ошибки в torch и kandinsky2

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

В общем у меня 2 вопроса.
1 я скачал модуль kandinsky2  на пк  и запустил такой скрипт

```
from kandinsky2 import get_kandinsky2
model = get_kandinsky2('cuda', task_type='text2img', model_version='2.1', use_flash_attention=False)
model = torch.load(map_location=torch.device('cpu'))
images = model.generate_text2img(
    "red cat, 4k photo",
    num_steps=100,
    batch_size=1,
    guidance_scale=4,
    h=768, w=768,
    sampler='p_sampler',
    prior_cf_scale=4,
    prior_steps="5"
)
```

Но после выполнения этого кода  выходит ошибка:

> Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but
> torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only
> machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu')
> to map your storages to the CPU.

(я пытался её решить, но без результатов)  2 ошибка связанна всё с той же либой, (я решил запустить этот скрипт в google colab) нооо опять ошибка

> AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'profiler'

пытался гуглить, но 0 результата (версия torch 2.0.0)